# NSTimer Press "Start" Again then Cannot "Stop"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

A strange situation:

If I started my Timer again and again without stopping it first, it will count increasingly fast. I guess it is because it starts multiple timers now?

However, when I finally want to stop it, it cannot be stopped...keep going forever.

(Maybe for design consideration, I should disable users from pressing start again, but I'm wondering what is really behind this and why the timer can't be stopped.)

```
- (IBAction)Start:(id)sender {
    countInt = 0;
    self.Time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countInt];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)Stop:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];
}

- (void) countTimer {
    countInt += 1;
    self.Time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countInt];
}
@end
```

Comment: show your code, presumably you aren't invalidating and you're also killing your reference to the timer...

Comment: Post the code, not pictures! - Edit your question.

Comment: @Wain Thanks for the quick reply! I added a screen shot... not sure if it's the right way to attach it. I did invalidate the timer.

Comment: @vadian Thanks! I just figured how to post the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is a property `timer`

```
@property NSTimer *timer;
```

the most reliable way to start and stop the timer only once respectively is to create two methods.

```
- (void)startTimer
{
    if (self.timer == nil) {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 
                                                      target:self 
                                                    selector:@selector(countTimer) 
                                                    userInfo:nil 
                                                     repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (void)stopTimer
{
    if (self.timer != nil) {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }
}
```

Both methods perform a check, so the timer can't be restarted while it's running and vice versa.

Now just call the methods in the `start/stop` IBActions (the names should start with a lowercase letter).

```
- (IBAction)Start:(id)sender {
    countInt = 0;
    self.Time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countInt];
    [self startTimer];
}

- (IBAction)Stop:(id)sender {
   [self stopTimer];
}
```

The benefit is pressing `Start` has no effect when the timer is already running.

Comment: Only a little thing: No check in `-stopTimer:` needed, because nothing will be done, if it is `nil`.

Comment: Actually that's right, but is it more efficient to send **two** messages to a nil pointer (one message and one redundant assignment) rather than make **one** check?

Comment: Wow, I really do not expect a performance problem in an action method because of two messages to nil vs. one message to not nil. (However, they optimized the behavior for message to nil.) It is simply for shortness of the code.

Comment: It's certainly not a *problem*, but personally I'm looking always for the most efficient code, not for the shortest.

Comment: I'm personally looking for the best readable, what is usually the shortest. (No, not when the shortness is a result of typical "C hacks".) However, it was a little remark. Not worth of an endless discussion. (I prefer Wain's answer.)

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution is to call `stop` at the beginning of the `start` method.

Note that in `stop` you should also set `timer = nil;`

Comment: Cool. Why should I set timer to "nil"? Do I always need to set objects to nil when I stopped them?

Comment: You want `timer` to be set to `nil` after invalidating it otherwise you may end up trying to reference the invalidated timer pointer again. By setting it to `nil`, you'll be safe from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit 'start' multiple times you are creating multiple timers. So you are getting multiple timers firing and executing your timer callback. In this timer callback you increment counters. Since there are many timers now, they are all incrementing your counter, hence explaining your rapid increase in the counter.

You can allow the user to tap Start twice, as long you can define what happens when you hit Start while the timer is already going. But you definitely need to `invalidate` the old timer before creating a new one.

```
- (IBAction)Start:(id)sender {
    ...
    // Stop previous timer before creating a new timer.
    if (timer != nil) {
        [timer invalidate]
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is "call stop" at the beginning of start the best way to invalidate the old timer?

Comment: It is one way. You can manually also call [timer invalidate]. Depends on the real implementation of the Stop method.